# Autoit Registering an protocal and executing program

Tags: protocols, autoit

I made a program which i want to launch with some protocal for eg : proto
Called like proto://122122  from the browser.

When the user clicks on the link it opens my program and sends the number ahead it as some variable or something.

I have basic knowledge of c++ but no knowledge on this topic
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the protocol to the registry, in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

In particular you need to create the following keys:

```
[HKCR\proto]
@="URL:My Protocol"
"Url Protocol"=""

[HKCR\proto\shell\open\command]
@="Path\To\My\Program.exe '%1'"
```

Then opening `proto://122122` will execute `Program.exe`, and the numbers will be available in `$CmdLine[1]` (assuming you are using AutoIt, as you tagged it like that but don't mention it at all).

Edit:

To programatically do the above in AutoIt, you will need to look at the registry functions, in particular [RegWrite](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/RegWrite.htm). Above I was lazy and gave a `.reg` file like answer, but in AutoIt it looks something like:

```
Local $sProtoName = "proto"

RegWrite("HKCR\" & $sProtoName)
RegWrite("HKCR\" & $sProtoName, "", "REG_SZ", "URL:My Protocol")
RegWrite("HKCR\" & $sProtoName, "Url Protocol", "REG_SZ", "")
RegWrite("HKCR\" & $sProtoName & "\shell\open\command")
RegWrite("HKCR\" & $sProtoName & "\shell\open\command", "", "REG_SZ", "Path\To\My\Program.exe '%1'")
```

As with all things registry, don't do it, if you don't know what you are doing. Modifying HKCR is relatively safe. The worst that will happen is you'll overwrite some other protocol and it's a bit of a pain to undo, but I still recommend doing some reading first. Google is your best friend as usual, but a small into like [this one](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsr/p/registrywindows.htm) is probably a good idea.

To remove the above code just delete the entire "HKCR\proto" key.

Comment: Oh sorry for that i forgot to type that because i created that with my mobile.  And where do i add that ? I mean register where ? Sorry i dont have any knowledge with all this stuff. xD

Comment: @kritya, it doesn't really matter, as the same principle would apply to any other language. I could have written `argv[1]` and it would be the same.

Comment: u didnt got me right. I mean how do i add my protocol to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT ?

Comment: @Kritya, Sorry, I assumed you knew that. I'll edit the post now.